# ASP.NET usercontrol, is it possible to have a design time comment?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Im making a small user control, i was wondering if it was possible to make some sort of comment, that is only visible design time. For example i would like to write in the top of my control that it requires a querystring parameter named userid. This way other developers can quickly see the requirements?

cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In markup use:

```
<%-- Your comment --%>
```

Or write this:

```
<% if (this.DesignMode) {%> 
  Some informative text
<% } %>
```

I tested that last one out in a test project. When I drag & drop a user control containing that code I get to see it (VS2010) and when I run it there's no trace whatsoever in the generated html.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using a [ControlDesigner Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.design.controldesigner.aspx).

**Edit**: You can also use

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
  if (this.DesignMode)
  {
    ...
    return;
  }
  ...
}
```